# Yii2 pjax.reload not working for gridview records update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, pjax

I have developed rows per page functionality for grid-view. With a Drop-down having options like 5,10,25,50,100. On-change any of the drop-down option I need to show selected number of rows for grid-view.  For That I have created a Pjax container having my grid-view like :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

$this->title = 'Test Cards';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="test-card-index">
        <?= $this->render('_search', [ 'model' => $searchModel ]) ?>   
    </div>
</div>

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'test_grid_pjax', 'enablePushState' => false, 'timeout' => 1000000]); ?> 

<div class="row">
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'class' => 'table table-bordered responsive',
    'id' => 'test_grid',
    'summary' => "<div class='summary'><label>Showing {begin} - {end} of {totalCount} items.</label></div> <div class='col-sm-6 pageDropdown'> <label>Records per page</label>  ".Html::dropDownList('pageSize', (int) Yii::$app->session->get('pageSize', Yii::$app->params['defaultPageSize']), Yii::$app->params['rowPerPage'], ['id' => 'pageSize', 'class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'return reloadGrid("test_grid_pjax",this.value)']) . "</div>",
    'layout' => '{summary}{items}<div class="pager">{pager}</div>',
    'options' => ['class' => 'main-grid grid-view full-table'],
    'columns' => [
        'cc_amount',
        'cc_number',                    
        'cc_type',
        'cc_status'
        ],
    ]);
?>
</div>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

_search.php looks like :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<div class="test-card-search">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'options' => ['data-pjax' => true , 'class'=>'search_form form-horizontal' ]

]); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'cc_number',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-5']); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'cc_number', ['class'=>'form-control col-sm-5','autofocus'=>true]); ?>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'cc_type',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-5']); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">                                
                <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'cc_type',[ "RESTRICTED" => Yii::t('app','RESTRICTED'), "UNRESTRICTED" => Yii::t('app','UNRESTRICTED')],['prompt' => Yii::t('app','All Types'), 'class'=>'form-control col-sm-5']); ?>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-blue']) ?>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','id'=>'resetButton','onclick'=>"location.href = '".Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('testcard/index')."';"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

action in Controller looks like:

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    if (Yii::$app->request->get('pageSize')) {
        Yii::$app->session->set('pageSize', (int) Yii::$app->request->get('pageSize'));
    }

    // to set the selected page number of the grid
    if (Yii::$app->request->get('page')) {
        Yii::$app->session->set('page',(int)Yii::$app->request->get('page'));
    } else {
        Yii::$app->session->set('page',1);
    }

    $searchModel = new TestCardSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

function reloadGrid() is like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function reloadGrid(id, value, url) {
$.pjax.reload({
    container: "#" + id,
    data: $('#search_form').serialize() + "&pageSize=" + value,
    url: url,
    push: false,
    replace: false,
    timeout: 1000000
});
}
</script>
```

On Searching thru any of the fields its reloads entire page and also sets search parameters in url. 
Another problem is that on changing 'pageSize' dropdown it works fine for first time only, on every other attempts it shows error in console like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined
at reloadGrid (index:53)
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (index:1)
```

Is it a problem of JS conflicts?
I have tried many solutions by googling it, but not get it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue that pjax was not parsing all the search fields in a grid filter. My solution/workaround/hack was to trigger a change event of a grid filter field, instead of calling pjax reload directly.

```
        $('.date-range-filter').trigger('change'); // this works

        /*  // this didn't parse all the values from my form 
        $.pjax.reload({
            container: "#grid-pjax"
        });
        */
```

It has to do with the way gridView collects the form values for submission. It actually builds a new dummy form for the grid column filters because there is no actual form for the header filters of gridview

In your case you should also inspect the source and make sure the form is id'd correctly

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'id'=> 'myFormId' // <---- try giving the form an id
    'options' => ['data-pjax' => true , 'class'=>'search_form form-horizontal' ]

]); ?>
```

You can also try using the pjax widget form selector attribute- 
instead of pjax begin and end. This will let pjax get all the input fields in that form automatically.

```
<?php
Pjax::widget([
    'id' => 'search-form', 
    'enablePushState' => false, 
    'enableReplaceState' => false, 
    'formSelector' => '#myFormId', // <-- the form to submit with pjax
    // 'submitEvent' => 'change', /// whatever you want 
    ]);
 ?>
```